# Check Date exist in Javascript date array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

I have an array of date object and want to check if supplied date exists in the array by array.indexOf method but it's always returning -1 (not found). Although date exists in the array.

[image: Please have a look at attachment.]

availableDates[62] and Date have the same value when I print in the console but the condition is returning false.

Comment: Show your code.  Not a screenshot from your console, but runnable code....

Comment: All we can do is guess if we have a photo of the output from your code.

Comment: You need to compare dates using the `getTime()` method. Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: A `new Date` will not equal another using `==`, you need to compare some value of the date.

Comment: @Quantastical I want to check date in array of Date.

Comment: @AamirNakhwa the problem is not how you are searching the array, the problem is how you are deciding whether or not two dates are equivalent. Dates are objects, and object equality is by *reference*: `new Date(2019, 0, 1) !== new Date(2019, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Something like this would do it: `const hasDate = ( date, dates, test = date.valueOf() ) => !! (dates .find (d => d.valueOf() == test) )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Date​.prototype​.get​Time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get the Unix time stamp to compare with

```
const arr = [new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date()];
const selectedDate = arr[1]; // choose any date here, I use this as example.

console.log(arr.some(date => date.getTime() === selectedDate.getTime())); // true
```

Comment: You're changing what OP was doing. OP was comparing two completely different date objects (one in an array, one created outside the array). You're comparing an array item with itself.

Comment: Updated my example.